# JavaDB gerando sequencia de ids com 3 digitos

Tags: java

Estou tentando aprender Hibernate com JPA, fiz um teste para gravar no banco JavaDB e percebi que o id autoincrement em vez de gerar uma sequencia inicial de um digito (1,2,3,4...) está gerando uma sequencia que começa no 1 e pula para o 101, 201, 301, 401... Ou seja, a cada novo registro ele adiciona 100 para o ID.

Como fazer para o autoincrement ficar normal, gerando 1,2,3,4?

Porque e qual utilidade dele gerar um id com essa sequencia?

Classe Cliente

```
@Entity
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=100)
    private String nome;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=250)
    private String endereco;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=8)
    private int rg;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=12)
    private int cpf;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date time;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public int getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(int rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public int getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(int cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

O teste na classe Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Worked!");
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("teste");

        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.setNome("Joao");
        cliente.setCpf(58756456);
        cliente.setDate(new Date());
        cliente.setTime(new Date());
        cliente.setRg(4568);
        cliente.setEndereco("Rua dos anjos n 666");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(cliente);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Screenshot da tabela no JavaDB:
[image: JavaDB]

**Edit: (Esqueci de por o persistence.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="teste" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
      <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:Teste01;create=true"/>
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/> -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/> -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316187/alter-a-table-column-with-auto-increment-by-1-in-derby

Comment: Eu estou usando Hibernate com JPA, o proprio Hibernate gera a tabela... Não crio a tabela manualmente

Comment: O problema de alterar a tabela pelo código é que isso não soluciona o problema... Quando ela for gerada de novo (caso seja removida) o problema continua, sem falar que eu teria que usar isso em todas as tabelas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do JPA 2.1 (Java EE 7) a anotação [Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) ganhou um atributo `columnDefinition` que pode ser utilizado para mudar a definição de um campo. Exemplo:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID", columnDefinition="INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1")
private int id;
```

Mas no caso do Derby (JavaDB é uma variação do Derby empacotado pela Oracle) incrementar por 1 é o padrão (veja [documentação oficial](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html))

Eu chutaria que você está vendo incrementos de 100 devido a [prealocação de valores](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefproperpreallocator.html). Provavelmente você não está "desligando" seu database, de forma que cada vez que você executa sua aplicação ela aloca um novo bloco.

Conforme [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804619/664577) as duas opções são:

1. Desligar o database (ou seja, abrir uma conexão para o seu database passando o parâmetro `;shutdown=true` antes de sair da sua aplicação).
2. Setar `derby.language.sequence.preallocator=1`, veja que isso potencialmente piora a concorrência entre sequências.

Comment: Anthony, para um pool de conexão onde não realiza o fechamento das conexões, apenas as sessões, a "columnDefinition" resolveria o problema?

Comment: Acredito que não, mas o parâmetro resolveria em troca de performance. Eu recomendaria o shutdown (você pode customizar sua aplicação ou o shutdown do seu servidor de aplicação. Alternativamente você pode rodar o JavaDB como um server separado ao invés de embedded e fazer o shutdown manualmente)

Comment: mas se eu tiro o ;create=true o banco de dados não é gerado na execução, ai como eu faço nesse caso? @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida Felipe. O seu `persistence.xml` pode ter `create=true` se a idéia é gerar um novo banco de dados (novos arquivos físicos) em cada execução. A minha sugestão foi para que você feche o banco ao desligar a aplicação (e.g, abra uma conexão JDBC simples com `shutdown=true`). Melhor ainda seria startar o Java DB em modo servidor e posteriormente fazer um shutdown manual.

Comment: eu nunca usei JavaDB, é a primeira vez que vejo essa opção... Então, eu manti a mesma configuração do meu persistence.xml que postei na pergunta, eu alterei somente a parte do `jdbc:derby:Teste01;create=true` para `jdbc:derby:Teste01;shutdown=true` acontece que com isso ele da erro afirmando que o DB não existe, e eu preciso que o DB seja gerado caso não exista, não posso usar uma conexão normal do jdbc, tenho que usar só o hibernate. (esqueci de por o persistence.xml na pergunta, agora eu coloquei!!!) @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Também tentei por os dois `jdbc:derby:Teste01;create=true;shutdown=true` Não deu, ele não cria o DB automaticamente, praticamente ignora esse comando create

Comment: Felipe. Não tem escapatória. Você precisa fazer um shutdown para evitar a releitura do log e problemas de alocação. Você pode: Fazer o shutdown com JDBC `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:Teste01;shutdown=true")`; ou abrir o banco em modo servidor e fazer o shutdown manual (veja a [documentação](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/twwdactivity4.html)) ou tentar fazer o shutdown usando a API do Derby ([documentação](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/adminguide/tadminconfig815357.html)). De qualquer forma a resposta é  persistence.xml com create e algo fazendo shutdown.